# When do I need to remove the badge icon count on android application?

Tags: android, uninstallation, badge

I implemented showing number of unread messages as badge on my android application launcher from the link [add notification badge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216806/how-to-add-a-notification-badge-count-to-application-icon-on-sony-xperia-devices) but the problem is when I uninstalled my application and installed it again I am still able to see the number of unread messages. I know that I have to set the badge count to zero before removing. My question is how do we know user is clearing cache/uninstalling the application? Is there any method when user clicks on uninstall? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute some set of code before uninstalling the app. OS did not give that permission to us. But As per your problem, You can set badge count(unread messages count) as soon as re-installing/installing as 0 if possible.

Comment: I am setting count to zero after installing, but user can see the badge until he opens the application after re-install/ install.

Comment: Okay. Will check and let you know.