# Meizu notification badge issue

Tags: android, notifications, badge

I'm trying to set a `Push Notification` badge on the app icon.

I have an issue with **Meizu** phone, It doesn't display the badges.
Does anyone has a solution for it?

I searched the stuck, but didn't find a solution for it.

I tried @Tadas Valaitis solotion from here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25849212/5223744

I also tried using [ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) library, but no luck.

Comment: you didn't share your issue...

Comment: @Dhruv Patel I added now, thanks.

Comment: have you seen in Logcat...? is there any errors?

Comment: Yep, there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

For your kind information, it is facility provided by **manufacturer**,

Please [read article](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000013/?category=5245260) provided by WhatsApp

[image]